# How to add 1 to all numbers == to 0 in a pandas dataframe column python

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently trying to calculate the length of disasters, measured in days, and then with this column that is the difference between the start date and end date, use groupby ( I think), in order to sum the length of disasters for each year, as my data set is from 1960 to present. Eventually, I'd like to also group it by disaster type as well to see how the length of particular disasters changed overtime, but one step at a time.

So far I have converted the dates to pd.datetime format, and then used the code below to create the column with the difference of the two dates

```
 #Create new Column == Disaster Length
df_time['Disaster_Length'] = (df_time.Start_Date_A - df_time.End_Date_A)
```

2 Part question:

A. How do I go about creating a loop along the lines of -- for i in column Start_Date_A ==0, add +1 -- Sorry I'm new with this, and need this to ensure even if a disaster started and ended on a day, it counts as 1 day and not 0.

B. What is the best way to go about changing the disaster length columng from a series to integers so they can be calculated?

Full Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd 
import seaborn as sns 

#Import Datased
df = pd.read_csv('database.csv')

df_time = (df[['County','Disaster Type','Start Date', 'End Date']][0: :])

           
#Number of NaN values          
df_nan = df[['County','Disaster Type','Start Date', 'End Date']].isna().sum()


#NaN values as a percentage as total 
df_nan_percent = (df_nan.sum(axis=0))
NAN_percentage = ['0.0116%']


#Remove NaN values
df_time.dropna(subset = ["County", 'End Date'], inplace=True)


#Set Date Format
df_time['Start_Date_A'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
df_time['End_Date_A'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')

#Create new Column == Disaster Length
df_time['Disaster_Length'] = (df_time.Start_Date_A - df_time.End_Date_A)


#Dropped Date Old Date Formats from df
df_time = df_time.drop(columns=['Start Date', 'End Date'], axis=1)

#Make County Column the Index, as NaN altered Index Consistency 
df_time.set_index('County', inplace=True)
```

Reproducible df

```
County,Disaster Type,Start_Date_A,End_Date_A,Disaster_Length
Clay County,Flood,1959-01-29,1959-01-29,0 days
Alpine County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Amador County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Butte County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Colusa County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Del Norte County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
El Dorado County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Glenn County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Humboldt County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Lake County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Lassen County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Marin County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Mendocino County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Modoc County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Napa County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Nevada County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Placer County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Plumas County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Sacramento County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
San Joaquin County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Shasta County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Sierra County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Siskiyou County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Solano County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Sonoma County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Stanislaus County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Sutter County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Tehama County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Trinity County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Tuolumne County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Yolo County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Yuba County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Baker County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Benton County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Clackamas County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Clatsop County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Columbia County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Coos County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Crook County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Curry County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Deschutes County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Douglas County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Gilliam County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Grant County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Harney County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Hood River County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Jackson County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Jefferson County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Josephine County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Klamath County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Lake County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Lane County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Lincoln County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Linn County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Malheur County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Marion County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Morrow County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Multnomah County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Polk County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Sherman County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Tillamook County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Umatilla County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Union County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Wallowa County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Wasco County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Washington County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Wheeler County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Yamhill County,Flood,1964-12-24,1964-12-24,0 days
Asotin County,Flood,1964-12-29,1964-12-29,0 days
Benton County,Flood,1964-12-29,1964-12-29,0 days
Clark County,Flood,1964-12-29,1964-12-29,0 days
Columbia County,Flood,1964-12-29,1964-12-29,0 days
Cowlitz County,Flood,1964-12-29,1964-12-29,0 days
Garfield County,Flood,1964-12-29,1964-12-29,0 days
Grays Harbor County,Flood,1964-12-29,1964-12-29,0 days
King County,Flood,1964-12-29,1964-12-29,0 days
Kittitas County,Flood,1964-12-29,1964-12-29,0 days
Klickitat County,Flood,1964-12-29,1964-12-29,0 days
Lewis County,Flood,1964-12-29,1964-12-29,0 days
Mason County,Flood,1964-12-29,1964-12-29,0 days
```

Comment: How lookd expected ouput? There is added `1` or `1,2,3`... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) for convert tiemdeltas to integers and then use `replace`:

```
df_time['Disaster_Length'] = (df_time.Start_Date_A - df_time.End_Date_A).dt.days

df_time['Disaster_Length'] = df_time['Disaster_Length'].replace({0:1})
```

Or set values by mask to `1`:

```
df_time['Disaster_Length'] = (df_time.Start_Date_A - df_time.End_Date_A).dt.days

df_time.loc[df_time['Disaster_Length'].eq(0), 'Disaster_Length'] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

First change the column creation code to:

```
df_time['Disaster_Length'] = (df_time.Start_Date_A - df_time.End_Date_A).dt.days
```

Then this should work:

```
for i in range(len(df_time)):
    if df_time.iloc[i]['Disaster_Length'] == 0:
        df_time.iloc[i]['Disaster_Length'] = 1
```

That way any disasters that lasted a day would be equal to 1 rather than 0.

Comment: When running both your and @heretolearn's answers, the data frame is returned the same, with the 0's unchanged. However, the logic seems right. Which makes me think I'd have to change it out of the datetime format before running these answers?

Comment: I think we both thought the last column was ints but it is actually "0 days" rather than "0" right? I changed my code to reflect this. Please see if it works now.

Comment: @jezrael has the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `lambda` function on `apply` method like this :

```py
df_time['Disaster_Length'] = df_time['Disaster_Length'].apply(lambda x : 1 if x ==0 else x)
```

Answer (score 0):

For making the no. of days as 1 if it started and ended on the same date, you could use `np.where` like:

```
df_time['Disaster_Length'] = np.where(df_time['Disaster_Length'] == 0, 1, df_time['Disaster_Length'])
```

As for the 2nd part, if both the start_date and end_date are in datetime format, you could just extract days, to get the day difference(i suppose that is what you want)

```
df_time['Disaster_Length'] = (df_time.Start_Date_A - df_time.End_Date_A).dt.days
```